# Configure query/command timeout with sqlalchemy create_engine?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The following Python code snippet illustrates the issue:

```
print("starting")

# I am trying to configure a query/command timeout of one second.
# sqlalchemy docs suggest execution_options but the documented list of options doesn't include a timeout:
# http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options
# Below, I am guessing at several likely timeout parameter names:
db_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:pass@server/catalog",
                          execution_options={"timeout": 1.0,
                                             "statement_timeout": 1.0,
                                             "query_timeout": 1.0,
                                             "execution_timeout": 1.0})

with db_engine.connect() as db_connection:
    print("got db_connection")

    # Artificially force a two second query time with pg_sleep.
    # This is designed to guarantee timeout conditions and trigger an exception.
    result_proxy = db_connection.execute("SELECT pg_sleep(2);")

    # If the timeout worked, this statement will not execute.
    # Currently, it does execute, which means my timeout isn't working.
    print("Query successfully complete. Got result_proxy")
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set configuration values like [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) via the [`options` parameter in `libpq`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-OPTIONS). You can access this parameter in `psycopg2` as part of the [`connect`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect) call. You can pass additional parameters to the `connect` call from SQLAlchemy via the [`connect_args`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-args) parameter. So, putting it all together:

```
engine = create_engine(..., connect_args={"options": "-c statement_timeout=1000"})
```

Comment: I'm not able to do this with mysql. I can't find anywhere in the mysql documents about statement timeout.

Comment: @Dilip MySQL is much more limited in functionality, but the closest equivalent (that only works on read-only `SELECT` statements) is [`max_execution_time`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time).

Answer (score 1):

It took me sometime to figure out how to set multiple options with `create_engine(...)` . In case, you are also looking for the same -

```
engine = create_engine(..., connect_args={'options': '-c lock_timeout=3000 -c statement_timeout=3000'})
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT): `If statement_timeout is nonzero, it is rather pointless to set lock_timeout to the same or larger value, since the statement timeout would always trigger first.`