# Set sqlite3 timeout to > 5 seconds in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy, timeout, flask-sqlalchemy

Spent the last 20 hours to solve this problem, no luck. I saw a "database is locked" first in my production server when > 100 people tried to register all at once (within 10 seconds), and tried recreating it using JMeter. When I run JMeter, every time it goes beyond 5 seconds I get the "database is locked" error. So, I think I successfully recreated the problem (at least after 20 hours !!!)

Almost everyone including [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) piece of documentation on sqlite3 recommends that the problem stems from the 5 seconds timeout.

I tried the following:

1- I don't know the equivalent of this in flask-sqlalchemy:

```
engine = create_engine(..., connect_args={"options": "-c statement_timeout=1000"})
```

which was accepted as the correct answer here:
[Configure query/command timeout with sqlalchemy create_engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936527/configure-query-command-timeout-with-sqlalchemy-create-engine)

2- This configuration doesn't have any effect:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.engine.execute("PRAGMA busy_timeout=15000;")
```

3- This configuration, will give the following error:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = 15
```

error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'pool_timeout' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/NullPool/Engine.
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @axwell I decided to switch to MySQL and haven't since experienced same issues. So far it's been great using MySQL.

Comment: @Greg it doesn't solve the problem, more like running from it