# sqlalchemy.pool + psycopg2 timeout issue

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a web application timeout issue, and I'm suspecting the error is in the database. The query is running too long.

How do I increase the allowed-running-time for my setup?

I am using a DB pool by using `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2`.

My database is a **Postgres** database.

```
  import psycopg2
  import sqlalchemy.pool as pool

  def generate_conn_string(db_name):
        db_name = db_name.upper()
        conn_string = "host='{}' port='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' ".format(
            os.environ.get('DB_HOST_' + db_name),
            os.environ.get('DB_PORT_' + db_name),
            os.environ.get('DB_NAME_' + db_name),
            os.environ.get('DB_USER_' + db_name),
            os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD_' + db_name))
        return conn_string

   def get_conn_():
        db_name = "mydb"
        conn_string = Pooling.generate_conn_string(db_name)
        conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        return conn

   connection_pool = pool.QueuePool(get_conn, max_overflow=30, pool_size=5)
```

Comment: Could you provide some traceback or logs with info on timeout you mentioned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking about [statement timeouts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) in PostgreSQL. The way you are using SQLAlchemy is a bit odd, but a vanilla SQLAlchemy constructor accepts an additional `connect_args` parameter that can be used as such

```
engine = create_engine(..., connect_args={"options": "-c statement_timeout=5000"})
```

Note that the timeout is in milliseconds. In your case, you can use [options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) with straight psycopg2/libpq:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string, , options='-c statement_timeout=5000')
```

Related question: [Configure query/command timeout with sqlalchemy create_engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936527/configure-query-command-timeout-with-sqlalchemy-create-engine)